# Calculating $\int_0^{2\pi}\left(\frac{r\cos(t-t_0)+r^2}{1+r^2+2r\cos(t-t_0)}\right)dt$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, analysis, definite-integrals

I'm trying to show that $$\int_0^{2\pi}\left(\frac{r\cos(t-t_0)+r^2}{1+r^2+2r\cos(t-t_0)}\right)dt$$ is equal to $2\pi$ when $r > 1$ and $0$ when $r < 1$. Assume $r>0$ here.

I essentially know this is correct, based on the larger calculation this is part of, and based on this desmos graph (https://www.desmos.com/calculator/cc6hnohoww). But I'm very stuck on how to properly use my knowledge of r to calculate the integral.

To provide some context: this is the imaginary part of a long tedious calculation of a contour integral from the definition of a contour integral. Specifically, I am showing that the integral along a circle of radius r at a point $z_0$ of $\frac{1}{z}$ is $0$ if the circle does not contain the origin, and $2\pi$ if it does contain the origin. I am not allowed to use Cauchy's theorem, or the complex logarithm as a primitive for $1/z$, I am specifically supposed to do it from the definition of the contour integral; IE, parameterize and split into real and imaginary parts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:**
$$\int_0^{2\pi}\left(\frac{r\cos(t-t_0)+r^2}{1+r^2+2r\cos(t-t_0)}\right)dt\\~\\＝\int_{0}^{2\pi}\frac {a\cos(t－t_0)＋b}{2a\cos(t－t_0)＋c}dt\\~\\＝\int_{－t_0}^{2\pi－t_0}\frac {a\cos(x)＋b}{2a\cos(x)＋c}dx\\~\\＝\frac {1}{2}\int_{－t_0}^{2\pi－t_0}\left({1＋\frac {2b－c}{2a\cos(x)＋c}}\right)dx\\~\\\boxed{\int\;\frac {1}{a\cos(x)＋b}dx＝\frac {-2\operatorname{arctanh}\left({\frac {(b－a)\tan\left({\frac {x}{2}}\right)}{\sqrt {a^2-b^2}}}\right)}{\sqrt {a^2-b^2}}}$$

Comment: When you factor out a $1/2$, shouldn't the inside be $\left(1 + \frac{2b-c}{2a\cos(x) + c}\right)$?

Comment: Thank's .Good Note .

Comment: $\tan$ is $\pi$ periodic, so shouldn't evaluating this last integral from $- t_0$ to $2\pi - t_0$ always give $0$? But then we are just left with $\int_{-t_0}^{2\pi - t_0} \frac{1}{2} dx$ which should be $\pi$. But then our integral should always be $\pi$. What am I missing here?

Comment: I figured it out. It was something to do with being careful with the domain of definition - instead of using this antiderivative, I ended up using Weierstrauss substitution directly

Answer (score 2):

The calculation can be performed without determining the antiderivative.

The integral does not depend on $t_0,$ hence we may assume $t_0=\pi.$ The integral is equal $\pi -I_r$ where
$$I_r:={1\over 2}\int\limits_0^{2\pi}{1-r^2\over 1-2r\cos t+r^2}\,dt $$
Observe that $I_r= -I_{1/r}.$
For $0<r<1,$ by summation of geometric progressions,  we get
$$\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty r^{|n|}e^{int}={1-r^2\over 1-2r\cos t+r^2}$$
The series is absolutely convergent and the integral of each term with $n\neq 0$ vanishes. Hence
$$\int\limits_0^{2\pi}{1-r^2\over 1-2r\cos t+r^2}\,dt=2\pi$$ Therefore, since $I_r=-I_{1/r},$ we obtain $$I_r=\begin{cases} \pi & 0<r<1\\
-\pi & r>1
\end{cases},\qquad \pi- I_r=\begin{cases} 0 & 0<r<1\\
2\pi & r>1
\end{cases}$$